# Transaction count after EXECUTE issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have written a procedure like below lines of code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CountrySave]
(
@CountryId uniqueidentifier,
@CountryName nvarchar(max)
)
AS 
begin tran
if exists (select * from Country where CountryID =@CountryId)
begin
update Country set 
CountryID = @CountryId,
CountryName =@CountryName
where CountryID = @CountryId
end
else
begin
insert INTO Country(CountryID, CountryName) values 
(NewID(),@CountryName)
end
```

It throws "Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.

A transaction that was started in a MARS batch is still active at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back." error message when executed!!! 
Please Help...

Comment: Add `COMMIT TRAN` at the end if everything is ok. You should wrap your transaction with `BEGIN TRY...BEGIN CATCH` and Rollback if error occurs

Comment: Can you please add code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `COMMIT TRAN`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CountrySave]
    @CountryId uniqueidentifier,
    @CountryName nvarchar(max)
AS 
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN

    if exists (select * from Country where CountryID =@CountryId)
    begin
         update Country
         set CountryID = @CountryId,
             CountryName =@CountryName
         where CountryID = @CountryId;
     end
     else
     begin
        insert INTO Country(CountryID, CountryName)
        values(NewID(),@CountryName)
    end

    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    /* Error occured log it */
    ROLLBACK
END CATCH
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is fairly clear. When you open (begin) a transaction, you will need to do something at the end of it as well.

So either you `ROLLBACK` the transaction (in case one of the statements within the transaction fails), or you `COMMIT` the transaction in order to actually implement all changes your statements made.

From MSDN:

> BEGIN TRANSACTION represents a point at which the data referenced by a
>   connection is logically and physically consistent. If errors are
>   encountered, all data modifications made after the BEGIN TRANSACTION
>   can be rolled back to return the data to this known state of
>   consistency. Each transaction lasts until either it completes without
>   errors and COMMIT TRANSACTION is issued to make the modifications a
>   permanent part of the database, or errors are encountered and all
>   modifications are erased with a ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statement.

More information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is that you begin a transaction but you never commit it / do a rollback.

Try this structure for your procedure, worked very well for me in the past:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].SomeProc
    (@Parameter INT)
AS
BEGIN
    --if you want to be to only active transaction then uncomment this:
    --IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    --BEGIN
    --  RAISERROR('Other Transactions are active at the moment - Please try again later',16,1)
    --END

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    BEGIN TRY
        /*
            DO SOMETHING
        */

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        --Custom Error could be raised here
        --RAISERROR('Something bad happened when doing something',16,1)

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH
END
```